# Links open and close via document.write

Tags: javascript, document.write, window.closed

I'am trying to use `window.close` with the following link below

```
myWin.document.write("<a href='#' onclick=\"newMovie.window.close('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2015381/','newMovie','height=600,width=600,left=400,top=100,scrollbars,status,resizable,dependent;')\"><b>Click Here to Close the Movie Window</b></a> <br><br>");
```

It isn't working. The idea is to be able to click and open one link which this works and click a second link to close the same window which isn't working.

Below are both links:

```
myWin.document.write("<div Id='box' style='text-align:center;");
myWin.document.write("<a href='#' onclick=\"window.open('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2015381/','newMovie','height=600,width=600,left=400,top=100,scrollbars,status,resizable,dependent;')\"><b>Click Here to Access the Movie Window</b></a> <br><br>");
myWin.document.write("<a href='#' onclick=\"newMovie.window.close('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2015381/','newMovie','height=600,width=600,left=400,top=100,scrollbars,status,resizable,dependent;')\"><b>Click Here to Close the Movie Window</b></a> <br><br>");
```

I'm missing something here? or is it easier to create a function() to close the link?

Comment: Tried removing `window` from `newMovie.window.close` ? `.close()` should not require parameters passed to be passed , `newWindow.close()` should reference `"newWindow"`

Comment: @guest271314 it didn't work.I open the link with the first one and click on the second to close it and nothing is happening.

Comment: Do you have any `newMovie` variable anywhere?

Comment: @Bergi no I don't have. since newMovie supposed to be the name of the window.open

Comment: @Sow: Yeah, but naming the window doesn't automatically create a variable. Use `var newMovie = window.open(…);` and `newMovie.close()`.

Comment: @Bergi it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You've missed a few points:

1. As [bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) mentioned in the comments, naming the window doesn't create a variable. Use `var newMovie = window.open(…)` and `newMovie.close()` instead. And the variable `newMovie` is the reference to the window you create. Also pay attention to that, `newMovie` should be a global variable. Reference: [window.open - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)
2. Be careful when you use [document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write). The text you write is parsed into the document's structure model. In this case, you've missed a close syntax in your code:

   yours: `myWin.document.write("<div Id='box' style='text-align:center;");`

   correct: `myWin.document.write("<div Id='box' style='text-align:center;'>");`

**You may not run the code directly, instead, copy all of it and run in your local `.html` file.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

 var newMovie = null; 

 document.write("<div id='box' style='text-align:center;'>");
 document.write("<a href='#' onclick='openNewWindow()'><b>Click Here to Access the Movie Window</b></a>");
 document.write("<a href='#' onclick='closeWindow()'><b>Click Here to Close the Movie Window</b></a>");

 function openNewWindow() {
  newMovie = window.open('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2015381/','newMovie','height=600,width=600,left=400,top=100,scrollbars,status,resizable,dependent;');
 }

 function closeWindow() {
  newMovie.close();
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```